# Summernote adding span after merging paragraphs

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4, wysiwyg, summernote

I'm attempting to build a content authoring application around Summernote (BS4) and have bumped into a feature that's not very helpful.

Given two paragraphs:

```
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.</p>
<p>One, two, three, four.</p>
```

If in the editor I use backspace to merge the two paragraphs, I would be expecting a result like...

```
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.One, two, three, four.</p>
```

This is exactly what you get if you try out the example implementation on [Summernote's homepage](https://summernote.org/)

But instead I am getting...

```
<p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.<span style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, &quot;Segoe UI&quot;, Roboto, &quot;Helvetica Neue&quot;, Arial, sans-serif, &quot;Apple Color Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Emoji&quot;, &quot;Segoe UI Symbol&quot;; font-size: 1rem;">One, two, three, four.</span></p>
```

(ie: a `<span>` element with lots of styling, surrounding what was the second paragraph)

Would really appreciate an explanation of what's going on here, and how I can prevent it.

Many thanks!

CDNs:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-bs4.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="summernote"></div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#summernote').summernote();
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I've noticed that if I use summernote-lite instead of summernote-bs4 and remove the BS4 CDNs, the problem no longer persists.

If I stick with summernote-lite but reintroduce BS4 then the problem returns!

CDNs without problem:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-lite.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-lite.js"></script>
```

CDNs with problem:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js" integrity="sha256-2Kok7MbOyxpgUVvAk/HJ2jigOSYS2auK4Pfzbm7uH60=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-lite.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/summernote/0.8.11/summernote-lite.js"></script>
```

Leading me to believe this is a Bootstrap related issue...

---

**UPDATE 2:**

This does in fact appear to be a Summernote issue which can in fact be replicated on their BS4 example found [here](https://summernote.org/getting-started/#for-bootstrap-4), which I've now reported on Github [here](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/3088).

Comment: seems like the second paragraph had lots of styling already applied to it. can you see the html source before merging them?

Comment: @NawedKhan html source of two paragraphs before merging is identical to first code block in original question :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I solved by adding css rules to note-editable class:

```
.note-editable * {
    line-height: inherit!important;
    font-size: 14px!important;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
 }
```

This fixed it for me.